# How to create draggable sheet reference with the same cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm not very familiar with Google Sheets and have a question that may be very simple but I can't seem to find an answer.

I am trying to pull information from one same cell example, `H47` from multiple sheets. If I type `'1'!H47`, is there a way for this sequence to follow? When I highlight the `'1'!H47` and drag, it keeps the sheet number and changes the cell.

How can I set it up for the sheet to change but not the cell?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use **`INDIRECT`** where you will freeze **`H47`** with quotes and make **`1`** "movable" like:

```
=INDIRECT(ROW(A1)&"!H47")
```

[image]

---

If you need to drag it to the right use:

```
=INDIRECT(COLUMN(A1)&"!H47")
```